# What does the JVM do in background before calling Thread.run()? OR Why Thread.run() isn't exposed to the user?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

A thread's run method is invoked by JVM when `Thread.start()` is called by the programmer.

1. What does the JVM do in background before calling `Thread.run()`?
2. Why is `Thread.run()` not exposed to the user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What does the JVM do in background before calling `Thread.run()`?

It does the JVM work to manage the thread object (allocate stack space, thread-locals, ...) and the per-architecture native work of forking and scheduling a new thread/process/clone or whatever the architecture uses to implement threads.

> Why is `Thread.run()` not exposed to the user?

I assume you are talking about "exposed" in terms of the stack frame.  Just like the the static `main` method, there obviously are call frames above the user code that aren't exposed to the user because they aren't useful and would be confusing.  I'd say the same thing about the `Thread.run()` method.  It *will* show up in the call stack if you extend `Thread` and override `run()` but *won't* if you are passing in a target `Runnable`.

I have a lot of details about this in this answer:

> [How does Java run() method work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763928/how-does-java-run-method-work/10765139#10765139)

Answer (score 1):

> What does the JVM do in background before calling Thread.run()?

When you call start() it starts a thread associated with the `Thread` object which calls the run() method of the thread.

Note: All the work of creating, starting and scheduling threads is done by the OS. Java just makes the right system calls.  It is not JVM code which does the real work.

> OR Why Thread.run() isn't exposed to the user?

It is exposed. It is public and you can call it like any other method.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the start by thread.run(), you are running this as a normal process and not really using it as a thread.  It will be joined with the main thread.  With thread.start(), the JVM allocates the separate thread which will not be joined with the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `start()`, the `Thread` class actually creates the new JVM thread (which is separate from the calling thread), and calls `run()` from that new thread.

Creating new JVM threads, so that application code can have multiple threads of running code, is a low-level JVM operation.

If `run()` were exposed to the user, and it were called instead of `start()`, then the code in `run()` will be executed serially in the single, calling thread.

Comment: 'sets up the new JVM thread' as in allocating memory in the stack? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

`someThread.start()` calls a native method which tells the JVM to create a new thread. The gory details for hotspot, for example, can be found [in the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp).

In substance, `start()` asks the os to create a new thread then calls the `Thread#run()` method in that newly created thread.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting to delve into the implementation of the JVM itself, as launching of a new thread requires interacting with the operating system.  Here's a [pretty good mid-level explanation](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/RuntimeOverview.html#Thread%20Management%7Coutline) of threads in the JVM.